# Sort search results based on sub string position

Tags: mysql

```
id | col1      | col2 |
_________________________
 1 | Aceh     | Denponda
 2 | Aceh     | Bonda Aceh
 3 | Sumatera | Asahan
 4 | Sumatera | Ondanar
```

And I use this query

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERe col2 LIKE '%onda%'
```

Now what happens here is it shows result like this

```
id | col1      | col2 |
_________________________
 1 | Aceh     | Denponda
 2 | Aceh     | Bonda Aceh
 4 | Sumatera | Ondanar
```

But I want is the row with id 4 takes the first place as its nearest on the similarity of the WHERE clause which is `onda`

This is my desired result

```
id | col1      | col2 |
_________________________
 4 | Sumatera | Ondanar
 2 | Aceh     | Bonda Aceh
 1 | Aceh     | Denponda
```

Basically what I want here is to sort the result accordingly 
 to the nearest similarity of the WHERE clause which is `onda` base on the value of the col2 from left to right

logically like this

- **Onda**nar
- B**onda** Aceh
- Denp**onda**

NOTE: the `id` column can't be use for sorting.

Comment: How do you define *similarity*?

Comment: Well its for a search result, I want the search results be sorted accordingly by which is the search term is nearest to the results from left to right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order by <kbd>[**`LOCATE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate)</kbd>

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM table 
WHERE col2 LIKE '%onda%'
ORDER BY LOCATE('onda', col2)
```

---

**Note:**

```
 LOCATE(substr,str), LOCATE(substr,str,pos)
```

> The first syntax returns the position of the first occurrence of
>   substring substr in string str. The second syntax returns the position
>   of the first occurrence of substring substr in string str, starting at
>   position pos. Returns 0 if substr is not in str.

Alternatively you can use <kbd>[**`INSTR`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr)</kbd> function

Comment: its just that simple?! WOW

Comment: Yes I guess so. :) You can also check the `INSTR` function. Please don't mind if if I rename the question title.

Comment: Yes thank you :), I don't know how to ask help for my problem. thank you :)

Comment: I believe you explained very well. Succinct indeed.